# List iterator returns last rows only c#

Tags: c#

There are two tables in the database.ModelTable and The values of the model.
The following code

```
 MyDB_Tables contain : ID|GroupNumber|ModelName|Picture
    ****
    MyDB_Tables Model_T = new MyDB_Tables(); 
    ArrayList ArrList = new ArrayList();
    List<long> T = new List<long>();
    for (int i=0 ; i<5; i++)
    {
      T.add(i);
    }
     foreach (var item6 in T)
    {
    
    var MyList =ECommerce_Rep.Return_ModelByID(Convert.ToInt64(item6));
      //Return_ModelByID is a function for return MyDB_Tables info by ID// 
    for (int k = 0; k < MyList.Count; k++)
       
    {

         Model_T.ID = MyList[k].ID;
         Model_T.GroupNumber = MyList[k].GroupNumber;
         Model_T.ModelName = MyList[k].ModelName;
         Model_T.Picture = MyList[k].Picture;
 
         ArrList.Add(Model_T);
    }
    }
```

Suppose, three numbers 1, 2, 3 are related to the ID. top code ,View on returns ID = 3 for 3 times.Like this

`ID =3 GroupNumber =1001 ModelName = CPU Core I3  Picture = 1.jpg`

---

`ID =3 GroupNumber =1001 ModelName = CPU Core I3  Picture = 1.jpg`

---

`ID =3 GroupNumber =1001 ModelName = CPU Core I3  Picture = 1.jpg`

---

what is solution?Thanks

Comment: You're readding the same element with properties changes. Initialize your object within the loop. + You should use generic `List<T>` instead of `ArrayList`.

Comment: Those are some of the absolutely worst names I've seen in years. Polish garbage names look better :/

Comment: Does `Return_ModelByID` really return a `List`? Sounds like it would just return a single Model.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your `MyDb_Tables` to a new instance inside your `for` loop instead of the single initialization you currently have outside the loop.

The reason is that otherwise the items you're adding to `ArrList` are all references to the same instance, and they're all getting updated in every iteration, so they all end up with the same values (that match the last item in `MyList`).

If you set it to a new instance inside the loop, then the references in `ArrList` will all be unique:

```
for (int k = 0; k < MyList.Count; k++)
{
     MyDB_Tables Model_T = new MyDB_Tables();

     Model_T.ID = MyList[k].ID;
     Model_T.GroupNumber = MyList[k].GroupNumber;
     Model_T.ModelName = MyList[k].ModelName;
     Model_T.Picture = MyList[k].Picture;

     ArrList.Add(Model_T);
}
```

While you're at it, you can also use a foreach and get rid of the index syntax, and you can directly add a new object using object initializer syntax:

```
foreach(var item in MyList)
{
     ArrList.Add(new MyDB_Tables
     {
         ID = item.ID,
         GroupNumber = item.GroupNumber,
         ModelName = item.ModelName,
         Picture = item.Picture
     });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem was resolved according to your instructions.

Comment: @TPRFPR so validate his answer by clicking on the V next to the first paragraph :-)